# Python: Does `multiprocessing.Process(...).start()` start all processes on the same cpu?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

Suppose I have a function that takes several seconds to compute and I have 8 CPUs (according to `multiprocessing.cpu_count()`).

What happens when I start this process less than 8 times and more than 8 times?

When I tried to do this I observed that even when I started 20 processes they were all running parallel-y. I expected them to run 8 at a time, others will wait for them to finish.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemptive_multitasking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens depends on the underlying operating system.

But generally there are two things: physical cpu cores and threads/processes (all major systems have them). The OS keeps track of this abstract thing called thread/process (which among the other things contains code to execute) and it maps it to some cpu core for a given time or until some syscall (for example network access) is called. If you have more threads then cores (which is usually the case, there are lots of things running in the background of the modern OS) then some of them wait for the context switch to happen (i.e. for their turn).

Now if you have cpu intensive tasks (hard calculations) then you won't see any benefits when running more then 8 threads/processes.  But even if you do they won't run one after another. The OS will interrupt a cpu core at some point to allow other threads to run. So the OS will mix the execution: a little bit of this, a little bit of that. That way every thread/process slowly progresses and doesn't wait possibly forever.

On the other hand if your tasks are io bound (for example you make HTTP call so you wait for network) then having 20 tasks will increase performance because when those threads wait for io then the OS will put those threads on hold and will allow other threads to run. And those other threads can do io as well, that way you achieve a higher level of concurrency.

Comment: My function is CPU intensive. I'm worried if I initiate more than 8 processes 
in parallel it will deteriorate the performance and maybe even break something if there are, say 40 such processes. Is that how it works? Does the OS manage process queuing for me, or do I have to explicitly do something about it?

Comment: @sP_ Yes, that's exactly what will happen. Processes themselves will perform accordingly. However the more processes you have the more context switch OS has to do (you don't see that and you can't affect that, the OS does whole work for you). And the context switch becomes a bottleneck at some point (with modern computers probably something around thousands of threads). So yes, your performance will deteriorate.

Comment: I see, one follow up question, if I use locks in my function, and say there are 10 processes waiting for the lock to release. Which process takes place when the lock is released? The one that was first called? Or is it something out of our control and is maintaining a queue the answer here as well?

Comment: @sP_ Locking is usually done in the kernel (OS) space (there are alternatives though). So first of all note that a locked process is similar to a process waiting for io. It is put on hold by the OS. Secondly when a process releases a lock then the OS picks a process that was waiting for the lock and schedules it for execution. So yes, there's a queue in the OS. The way that OS picks a waiting process is an implementation detail and you can assume it is at random.

Comment: Thanks, I tried few simulations with locks and it seems to be working as expected.